# How to show subclass of UIControl in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, iboutlet, uicontrol

I would like to be able to interact with the UIControl I have made, and therefore want it in my ViewController.

**What I tried**

- I subclassed UIControl (1).
- Then I added a UIView to my View Controller and assigned it the new class (2).

But in Interface Builder I am not able to set my outlets to the buttons contained in the new class (1)?!

1: [image: 1]

2: [image: 2]

[UIControl's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html) confirms that it is a subclass of UIView, and I should therefore be able to connect the outlets, right?

What am I missing here? :/

Comment: How did you try to connect the outlets? Select WeekdayControl in IB and  go to connections inspector, from there you can connect the outlets to your buttons in IB.

Comment: Yes, this is how I tried to connect them. I tried to drag-and-drop but nothing seems to be wiling to connect. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can't add an **@IBOutlet** because the buttons that you've added to `WeekdayControl` are in `UIViewController`.

You can't add an **@Outlet** to `WeekdayControl` buttons are only subviews of `WeekdayControl`.

`UIViewController` is the boss here, and you can only add an @outlet to `UIViewController`.

Better create your buttons programmatically in `WeekdayControl`.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the Interface Builder 101 I couldn't get my head around.

Answer (score 1):

**Must read first:-**

> You cannot use the UIControl class directly to instantiate controls.
>   It instead defines the common interface and behavioral structure for
>   all its subclasses.
>
> The main role of UIControl is to define an interface and base
>   implementation for preparing action messages and initially dispatching
>   them to their targets when certain events occur

*So, you are doing wrong, if you really need to make a custom view or custom control then you can directly do it by creating a custom UIView and connecting the outlets  directly with the view.*

I think you missing the objective of subclassing a UIControl, it doesn't give rights to create outlets as it's a subclass of UIView,**just read this lines what it is stated in the docs:-**

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> You may want to extend a UIControl subclass for either of two reasons:
>
> To observe or modify the dispatch of action messages to targets for
>   particular events
>
> To do this, override sendAction:to:forEvent:, evaluate the passed-in
>   selector, target object, or UIControlEvents bit mask, and proceed as
>   required.
>
> To provide custom tracking behavior (for example, to change the
>   highlight appearance)
>
> To do this, override one or all of the following methods:
>   beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:,
>   continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:, endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:.

Comment: But the reason I made the control was to decouple variables stored there, and access them through the control. Without the control my view controller is really bloated. :/
I get that it might not be best practice, but I still do not understand why it is not possible?!

Comment: You are wrong buddy, you said "it might not be best practice" , it is not at all a way to create custom control ;)